# ASM Java bycode muniplation changing a class name

Tags: java, bytecode, java-bytecode-asm, bytecode-manipulation

So recently I been trying to simply just change a class name and I just cant .
Here is my code 
InjectorClassNode
https://0bin.net/paste/9REMNddwqjm8vRms#hyr4RG3BI36J+kRwMfC2pJoXb7I3+7AwKKzYhhXZQfw

MethodClassNode
https://0bin.net/paste/UwKCvIG+cliZAYja#gILvBXxaQ1CyfQ602c6h7UE9dimhlo6q+GbKIwZ6m8B

Now when I run it , it throws a class not found for some stuiped reason "com/kirelcodes/cool/Task" is in the import list and I dont know why
I would love to get help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your solution you would only be renaming the class in one file. The other classes won't be notified of the name change and will throw "ClassNotFoundException".

It would be better to rename the class after you have done your modification with a Remapper.

Comment: I actually did update refernces the problem is that at the end there is an import that is useless  for the original name

Comment: @NacOJerk: did you read and attempt to understand [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40152920/2711488)? Your code doesn’t do what you intent, i.e. it doesn’t rename anything. `import` statements are pure source code artifacts that don’t show up in the bytecode at all.

Answer (score 1):

The `signature` parameter of all `visit…` methods refers to the *generic signature*, which is relevant to Reflection only at runtime. You should have noticed, that the class visit method has a `name` parameter which is much more relevant to the *name* of the class, which is what you want to change.

For the members, it’s not so obvious that the `desc` parameter is what the JVM specification calls “*signature*”, but at least, the ASM API is consistent in calling the *generic signature* description parameters `signature`. That’s why the `signature` can be `null`, which indicates that there are no generic types involved. For what you want to achieve, you have to adapt the `desc` parameter.

Further, note that when processing the instructions, you not only have to care for converting the owner type of referred members, the types of the members have to be adapted too. It’s not helpful to name the parameters `arg0, arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4` in this context, by the way. There might be additional type references you are not processing, e.g. `ldc` instructions may push a `Class` reference, but I don’t know whether this matters for this specific case.